# How to properly design a functor that would fetch different fields from a struct

Tags: c++, functor

I have a `std::vector` of `struct`s that contain several fields, like the following:

```
struct stats
{
   double mean;
   double median;
   double rms;
};
std::vector<stats> data;
```

I'd like to design a function that operates on the `vector`, for example, builds a histogram. I'd like to be able to specify what filed of the `struct`s should this function operate on. For example:

```
build_histogram(data, get_mean);
build_histogram(data, get_median);
build_histogram(data, get_rms);
```

I tried to implement some getters in the `stats` class, like this:

```
struct stats
{
   double mean;
   double median;
   double rms;
   struct get_mean { double operator() () { return mean; };
   struct get_median { double operator() () { return median; };
   struct get_rms { double operator() () { return rms; };
};
```

But it says that's an invalid use of non-static members `mean`, `median` and `rms`.
How could I implement it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to pass a type rather than an object. When iterating on a container the functor should accept the vector element as a parameter. There are several ways to do this, the one most similar to what you're trying to do is:

```
struct stats
{
   double mean;
   double median;
   double rms;
   struct get_mean { double operator() (const stats& s) { return s.mean; } };
   struct get_median { double operator() (const stats& s) { return s.median; } };
   struct get_rms { double operator() (const stats& s) { return s.rms; } };
};

build_histogram(data, stats::get_mean());
build_histogram(data, stats::get_median());
build_histogram(data, stats::get_rms());
```

However if you have support for lambdas (new in C++11) it's simpler to use them.

```
struct stats
{
   double mean;
   double median;
   double rms;
};

build_histogram(data, [](const stats& s) { return s.mean; });
// etc.
```

For either of these to work `build_histogram` should be a function template with the second parameter being any callable object (change `ReturnType` as appropriate).

```
template <typename F>
ReturnType build_histogram(const std::vector<stats>& data, F functor)
{
     // here you can use functor() or pass it to STL algorithm (e.g. find_if)
}
```

The different ways to define the functors are (more or less in the order of my preference)

- lambda function (C++11)
- free function
- functor object (this is what you did but it doesn't have to be nested in the type)
- static member function
- member functions using `std::bind` (I would not advise this)

Comment: In this case, getters could be a non-member classes?

Comment: Also, how should I call these functors inside the `build_histogram`? Let it be declared like `void build_histogram(std::vector<stats> data, functor getter)`. Should it be `data[i].getter()`?

Comment: Inside `build_histogram` they are called `functor(data[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Why to reinvent tuple?

```
enum {mean, median, rms};
typedef std::tuple<double,double,double>  stats;
stats   st{1,2,3};
cout << get<mean>(st);
```

Comment: I have 22 statistical attributes actually in my `stats`. I dont think they made a specification for 22 template parameters.